# How to swap 2 items using Draggable and Droppable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

### Problem

I have 4 images. User can drag and drop them to another list and change the order of the images. Target is that the users selects the order of the images. The problem is that I am unable to swap these images when they are place on each other.

### HTML

```
<ul id="choices">
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=1" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=2" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=3" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=4" /></li>
</ul>

<ul id="answers">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

### jQuery

```
(function ($) {

    $("#choices li img").draggable({
        revert: true,
        zIndex: 10,
        snap: "#answers li",
        snapMode: "inner",
        snapTolerance: 40
    });

    $("#answers li").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = this;

            if ($(droppedOn).children().length > 0) {
                alert("I need to swap these");
            }

            $(dropped).detach().css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }).prependTo($(droppedOn));
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

### CSS (not realy important)

```
img {
    display: block;
    z-index: 3;
}
#choices, #answers {
    display:block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#choices li, #answers li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #515151;
}
#answers li {
    position: relative;
}
```

### Example

http://jsfiddle.net/K6QNg/

Comment: Before I continue reviewing this, I just wanted you to know that 'choises' has a 'c' lol oh and you're traversing the DOM with Sizzle way more than necessary.  `$("#choises li img")` should be `var $img = $('#choices').find('img');`

Comment: @Deryck Could even be faster, this is just an example :) [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-sizzle/3)

Comment: @Bondye haha well I don't like to brag but um...mine's the Chrome 31 that's longer than every other one combined. lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution might not be the most elegant (maybe someone can provide something more intuitive?), but it seems it works ;)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W9Z46/14/

```
(function ($) {
    var lastPlace;

    $("#choises li img").draggable({
        revert: true,
        zIndex: 10,
        snap: "#answers li",
        snapMode: "inner",
        snapTolerance: 40,
        start: function (event, ui) {
            lastPlace = $(this).parent();
        }
    });

    $("#answers li").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = this;

            if ($(droppedOn).children().length > 0) {
                $(droppedOn).children().detach().prependTo($(lastPlace));
            }

            $(dropped).detach().css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }).prependTo($(droppedOn));
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

As you can see I'm just keeping the place you started draggin from in a variable `lastPlace` and later when you drop and check something is there, you place it in the place you started dragging before.

Answer (score 0):

I also to encountered same problem.But my code is a little different.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var x=[60,270,480];
    var y=[170,170,170];

    $(".draggable").draggable({
        revert:"invalid",
        start:function(){

        }
    });

    $(".droppable").droppable({
        accept:".draggable",
        hoverClass:"active",
        drop:function(ev,ui){
            if($(this).attr("name")!=null){
               var d=$(this).attr("name");
               var dgid=$(ui.draggable).attr("data-id")-1;
               $("#"+d).animate({left:x[dgid],top:y[dgid]});
               $("#drop"+$(ui.draggable).attr("data-id")).attr("name",$(this).attr("name"));
               $("#"+d).attr("data-id",$(ui.draggable).attr("data-id"));
            }
            var dpid=$(this).attr("data-id")-1;
            $(this).attr("name",$(ui.draggable).attr("id"));
            $(ui.draggable).attr("data-id",$(this).attr("data-id"));
            $(ui.draggable).animate({left:x[dpid],top:y[dpid]},300);
        }
    });
});
```

**Check out [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zamir/x6050k5u/)**

Answer (score -1):

You should probably try with  [sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) instead of droppable in the receiving list. That should give you the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Does this really answers the question?

Comment: I really think it's the way to go. It's the correct plugin for this functionality. Last year I had to do something similar to that, and I also try to use droppable, but there was no elegant solution with that plugin. I ended up using sortable, which already handles receiving items from other lists and gives you the possibility of swapping elements (since that is the all purpose of that plugin).

Comment: You might need to look at [Answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: While I also usually frown on answers that don't actually answer the question being asked, in this case I think it's a relevant consideration. He's essentially using draggable/droppable to recreate the behavior of sortable, and considering he's obviously already using jQueryUI, it's probably not difficult to switch interactions.  I think it was at least worth mentioning, even if it could possibly be considered off topic.