# Append draggable to droppable after swap

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've searched for this question but couldn't find it yet. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Hopefully I can help more people if this question gets answered.

I'll explain the situation first:

HTML

```
<div id="p1" class="base"> <!-- this is a box --> 
<div class="card">1</div>  <!-- this is a dynamically created div -->

</div>
<div id="p2" class="base">
<div class="card" style="background-color: green">2</div>

</div>
```

I have multiple boxes that act like a droppable. When you click on a box, a div will be created and appended to the box and the div is a draggable.

I've already figured out how to drag the div between multiple boxes.
Here is the problem:

When there's each box has a div dropped into it, I want to be able to swap the div between boxes and also append them to the box new box.

For example:
box 1 has div 1 and box 2 has div 2. I want to swap them so box 1 has div 2 and box 2 has div 1 appended to them as a child.

I also made an example which roughly shows how I currently have my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/h7ySb/

```
$(".card").draggable({
 revert: true,
 zIndex: 10,
 snap: ".base",
 snapMode: "inner",
 snapTolerance: 40,

 start: function (event, ui) {
    lastPlace = $(this).parent();
 }

});

$(".base").droppable({
 drop: function (event, ui) {

    ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));

    var dropped = ui.draggable;
    var droppedOn = this;

    if ($(droppedOn).children().length > 0) {
        $(droppedOn).children().detach().appendTo($(lastPlace));
    }

}
});
```

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269976/how-to-swap-2-items-using-draggable-and-droppable?rq=1) looks a bit like what I want, but it doesn't append the draggable to the new droppable.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I fixed it myself, so if anyone is having the same problem. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Colinch/h7ySb/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer myself.

You can find it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Colinch/h7ySb/6/

If you use dynamically created divs that are being swapped, you need to change the code a little bit.

When creating the dynamic created div:

```
element.draggable({
            revert: true,
            zIndex: 10,
            snap: ".base",
            snapMode: "inner",
            snapTolerance: 40,
});
```

and you have to put the code for the droppable outside the function where you create your div:

```
$(".base").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var dropped = ui.draggable;
                var droppedOn = this;
                lastPlace = dropped.parent().attr("id");

                if ($(droppedOn).children().length > 0) {

                    $(droppedOn).find(".card").detach().appendTo($("#"+lastPlace));

                }

                $(dropped).detach().css({
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0
                }).appendTo($(droppedOn));


            }

        });
```

I should thank the guy from the other question (see link in my first post) for some of the code.
Hopefully I can help someone with this.

Comment: Only problem I still have is: the divs' content is sometimes being selected when dragging. Does anyone know how to solve this?